# How to make 'while' loop count between numbers?

Tags: c#

I have a program that has two text boxes for input.  They are variableOne and VariableTwo.  I can't figure out the expression that i need to put in the for loop to show these numbers and the numbers in between them.  For example if i put a 1 and 11 i need 2-10 in between those. This is what i have so far.. I know i don't have the else expressions yet either.

```
namespace loops
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void whileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double variableOne = 0;
            double variableTwo = 0;
            int i = 0;


            if (double.TryParse(variableOneText.Text, out variableOne))
            {
                if(double.TryParse(variableTwoText.Text, out variableTwo))
                {
                    while(i<= (variableOne) && (variableTwo))
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    outputLabel.Text = i.ToString();

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I am having hard time trying to understand your question

Comment: We can help you with code, but noone will write it for you, show what you have till now

Comment: OK so i have to enter a first number for example i enter a 1 then i have to enter a second number says a 10.  I can't figure out what expression to put in the operations.. this is what i have so far..(I know i dont have the else for my try,parse either)

Comment: private void whileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double variableOne = 0;
            double variableTwo = 0;
            int i = 0;


            if (double.TryParse(variableOneText.Text, out variableOne))
            {
                if(double.TryParse(variableTwoText.Text, out variableTwo))
                {
                    while(i<= (variableOne) && (variableTwo))
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    outputLabel.Text = i.ToString();

Comment: IS there a better way to veiw the code easier?

Comment: Please see [help]

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear what you want to achieve.

I make a guess here:

INPUT: two rational numbers. 
OUTPUT: all natural numbers in between.

e.g. IN 8.1, 14.9 -> OUT 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

here's the code

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
double variableOne = 8.1;
double variableTwo = 14.9;

double start = 0;
double end = 0;

bool isShowingInitialVariable = true;


//if (double.TryParse(variableOneText.Text, out variableOne))
//{
//    if (double.TryParse(variableTwoText.Text, out variableTwo))
//    {


//take allways the smaller number to start and the greater for end
start = Math.Min(variableOne, variableTwo); 
end = Math.Max(variableOne, variableTwo);

//build your output
output.AppendLine(string.Format("first variable {0}, second variable {1}", variableOne, variableTwo));
output.AppendLine(string.Format("min", start));
output.AppendLine(string.Format("max", end));
output.AppendLine(string.Format("difference {0}", end - start));


//all the natural numbers in between.
for (int i = (int)Math.Ceiling(start); i < Math.Floor(end); i++)
{
    output.AppendLine(i.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
//        outputLabel.Text = output.ToString();

//    }

//}
```